# On dimension estimate of Brill-Noether Locus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth curve of genus $g$ on a $K3$ surface $X$ such that $\text{gon}(C) =k$ and $\text{cliff}(C) =k-2$. Then we have the following dimension estimate result,

If the linear system $|C|$ is base point free with the corresponding  Brill-Noether number $\rho(g,1,k) \leq 0$, then for $d \leq g-k+2$ every irreducible component of $W^1_d(C)$ has dimension atmost $d-k$.

At this point my Question is that : Does there exist analogous result for smooth curves $C$ lying on a general surface of $\mathbb P^3$ of degree $\geq 5$?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: I have doubts about your statement for K3. Can you give a reference?

Comment: @abx, The reference that I have got is theorem $3.7$ of the article [link]( https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.1522.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! Indeed the paper you quote give this statement. But they refer to a paper of Aprodu-Farkas, who prove it for a **general** curve in $|C|$. I have counter-examples for special cuves.

Comment: @abx, Is there any analogous result for general curve in $|C|$ in the case of hypersurfaces of degree bigger than $5$ in $\mathbb P^3$?

Comment: It might be true, but I don't think it is known. Note that since your surface is general your curve is a complete intersection. Some things are known about these (e.g. the Clifford index), but I don't think such a precise result is known.